# what is the specific difference between <html:submit tag and <input type="submit "?

Tags: java, html, validation, jakarta-ee, struts

what is the specific difference between `<html:submit` tag and `<input type="submit "`?

what is the advantage rather than we use `<html:submit` instead of `<input type="submit"`?

Answer (score 4):

> input type...

is a HTML tag and hence is interpreted at client side from browsers.

> html:submit...

is a struts tag library, is evaluated server side and after evaluation it emits the corresponding HTML tag which is <input type....

Answer (score 1):

Benefits of using 'html:' is that they work with the backing form bean.

Advantages (for other html: tags)

- will populate with form variables set in the action
- you will get errors on your jsp page when you try to use a form property that DNE.

As far as `<html:submit` goes, I can't think of any clear advantage of using it over `<input type="submit"` other than having all of your form tags "look the same".